# How to create android studio plugin for Project Popup Menu?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am trying to create an android studio plugin in Intellij editor.
I am able to create and test it on the Intellij editor itself by

```xml
<actions>
                <group id="MyPlugin.PluginMenu" text="Action Group" description="Action Group"
                >
                    <add-to-group group-id="ProjectViewPopupMenu" anchor="first"/>
                    <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"/>
                    <action id="Myplugin.Textboxes" class="main.java.PluginAction" text="Plugin Action"
                            description="Action"/>
                </group></actions>
```

But after prepare the plugin for deploymentthe menu is not showing in the Android Studio Project Popup Menu where as the same is working fine with the Intellij.

Can anybody help on this?
Or anybody have any tutorial on how to create Android studio plugin in intellij for Project Popup  Menu ?

Please help me

Comment: Do you use custom action group?

Comment: Can you please provide some examples or tutorials?